# Enable modern look sites by default

Tags: modern-experience, modern-pages, intranet, default

Is it possible to set a modern look as default for sites to an intranet that is already created?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, you are tying to make your Modern page as a Landing page for your intranet portal, if yes. you can navigate to site content -> site pages -> select your modern page and on ribbon click command bar and click make Hompage.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was, is it possible to set it so that when you create a new site it is set up as modern automatically by default?

Comment: I think, there is no option to create Modern site by default, Modern site is just a template, where user's can utilize the modern UI. and moreover you can't create the modern page at admin center or inside the site pages library... You can create the Modern page only by clicking GoG symbol and add page.. if you want you can make it as a Home Page.. thats the option we have in sharepoint